# How to discard stderr in restricted Bash shell?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, restricted-shell

In my .bashrc there are a couple commands which [redirect standard error  to /dev/null](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/29c2a28c840ae3ff6e740f3717e8480647036eee/.bashrc#L14), and this is not allowed within `rbash`:

```
bash: /dev/null: restricted: cannot redirect output
```

Is there some way to get around this (short of modifying Bash)? That is, to either

- discard standard error some other way or
- only attempt to redirect if it's allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can close stderr as in:

```
ls /blah 2>&-
```

While that will work in most cases, it may cause problems as poorly written applications may end up opening a new file which would automatically get `2` as the file descriptor and could end up writing error messages where you wouldn't want them to.

That also means that any write to stderr done by the application would return with an error (EBADF) which may affect their  behavior.

As pipes are allowed, you could provide with a command that discards all its input. Here, using `grep -v '^'` (but you could use `tail -n 0` or `sed d` or a script called `discard` that does `cat > /dev/null`):

```
{ ls /blah 2>&1 >&3 | grep -v '^'; } 3>&1
```

Alternatively, you could have whatever starts that restricted shell start it with the fd 3 (for instance) redirected to `/dev/null` (`rbash 3> /dev/null`), so you can then do within the restricted shell:

```
ls /blah 2>&3
```

Which is allowed:

```
$ rbash -c 'ls /blah 2>&3' 3> /dev/null
$
```

You can check whether redirection to `/dev/null` is allowed/works or not with:

```
if true 2>&- > /dev/null; then
  echo allowed
fi
```

You can check whether the shell is restricted or not with:

```
case $- in
  (*r*) echo restricted
esac
```

Comment: According to `man rbash` you won't be able to do any redirecting (even to closed) from within the shell. I think pipes are forbidden also.

Comment: @Yuugian, it's only redirections that can cause the shell to create a file that are prohibited. Input redirections (`<`) and pipes (which are more a way to run concurrent processes with their stdout and in connected), including process substitution and command substitution are allowed. You can double-check the manual and try it for yourself.

Comment: This actually works! Create a file test.sh with the lines `echo fail >&2` and `echo success`, `chmod u+x test.sh`, `PATH=$PATH:. rbash`, then run `test.sh` and `test.sh 2>&-` to verify.

Answer (score 2):

From `man rbash` it looks like any redirect is prohibited: (the following are disallowed or not performed)`redirecting output using the >, >|, <>, >&, &>, and >> redirection operators`

It does look like you can spawn another shell script to do the redirect because `When  a  command that is found to be a shell script is executed, rbash turns off any restrictions in the shell spawned to execute the script.`

So, while you couldn't `$ foo 2>/dev/null` it looks like you could run `$ bar` where bar contains
`#/bin/bash

foo 2>/dev/null`

It would have to be set up in advance from a full bash environment because rbash also disallowed `specifying command names containing /` which looks like it would prohibit your current directory`./bar` but not the implicit `/bin/bar`

Please note: I haven't tried this yet

Comment: If you can do that, it is surely a bug in _restricted_ bash...

Comment: that's why I was thinking that you would have to set it up from outside the rbash. If your `cwd` is not in $PATH then it is not much of a hole. rbash keeps you from using `cd`, calling a program not in $PATH, or changing $PATH

Comment: rbash stinks.
I have never used it and gladly so.